# Pointer to local variable outside the scope of its declaration

Tags: c, memory

Let's say I have a structure representing a PDF document `pdf` and a structure representing one of its pages `pdf_page`:

```
typedef struct pdf_page {
    int page_no;
    pdf_page *next_page;
    char *content;
} pdf_page;

typedef struct {
    pdf_page *first_page, *last_page;
} pdf;
```

From my `main()`, I call `create_pdf_file(pdf *doc)`:

```
void main() {
  pdf doc;
  create_pdf_file(&doc);
  // reading the linked list of pages here
}
```

Assume that `create_pdf_file` is something along these lines:

```
void
create_pdf_file(pdf *doc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pdf_page p;
        p.page_no = i;
        p.contents = "Hello, World!";
        doc->last_page->next_page = p;
    }
}
```

(This is merely an example source code, so no list processing is shown. Obviously, the `first_page` and `last_page` members of `pdf` need to be set first.)

*My question:* If I access `doc->first_page` - as well as the other pages in the linked list - after the `create_pdf_file()` call in my `main()`, is it possible that I get segmentation faults because of "taking the local variable `p` out of its context"?

(I am not sure whether I have guaranteed that the corresponding memory location will not be used for something else.)

If so, how do I avoid this?

Comment: I haven't used C in a while but I don't think you can pass a `pdf` into a function that is expecting a `pdf *`.

Comment: Also `pdf_page p` is located only inside that for loop.  Looking at your source I think you want to `malloc` each `pdf_page p`.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, p is a local variable stored on the stack, when the lifetime ends (every loop iteration) any pointer to it gets invalid. you need to allocate every page with malloc() and free() it after you are finished.
this would look similar to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
        pdf_page* p = malloc(sizeof(pdf_page));
        p->page_no = i;
        p->contents = "Hello, World!";
        doc->last_page->next_page = p;
}
```

and when you call your function you have to pass a pointer to doc:

```
create_pdf_file(&doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible that I get segmentation faults because of "taking the local variable p out of its context"?

Once the block in which `p` is declared terminates, any pointer to `p` is invalid (a "dangling pointer") and attempting to dereference such a pointer is Undefined Behaviour. In other words, don't do it: you could get segmentation faults, or any other behaviour (including random memory corruption or the use of the wrong data without any error condition.)

> (I am not sure whether I have guaranteed that the corresponding memory location will not be used for something else.)

You've guaranteed that the lifetime of `p` is shorter than a pointer to `p`.

> If so, how do I avoid this?

Use `malloc` to dynamically allocate a memory region of the correct size to hold the datum. Don't forget to `free` the memory when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, too. I do not know how could I have forgotten about trying `malloc()`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Although I edited the answer, I believe that my use of "out of scope" is pretty normal. For example, ISO/IEC 9899:201x draft (n1570): section 6.2.4p7 "lifetime extends ... until execution of the program leaves the scope of the declaration." To be fair, p6 prefers the usage "until execution of that block ends in
any way", but I think that it demonstrates that people writing in a much more formal context than SO feel that it's acceptable to say "leaves the scope". (The verb "leaves" and the verbal phrase "goes out of" are synonyms, at least in my idiolect of English.)