# Pointer to local variable is stored outside the scope of this variable

Tags: c++, c

For the following code snippet, which is a part of [libgearman](https://github.com/p-alik/gearmand/blob/master/libgearman/worker.cc#L668-L672)

```
gearman_job_st *gearman_worker_grab_job(gearman_worker_st *worker_shell,
                                        gearman_job_st *job,
                                        gearman_return_t *ret_ptr)
{
    if (worker_shell and worker_shell->impl())
    {

        ...

        gearman_return_t unused;
        if (ret_ptr == NULL)
        {
            ret_ptr= &unused;
        }
        ...
    }

    assert(*ret_ptr != GEARMAN_MAX_RETURN);
    return NULL;
}
```

[PVS-Studio](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V507/) reported:

```
Viva64-EM
full
671
/nfs/home/xxx/src/gearmand/libgearman/worker.cc
error
V506
Pointer to local variable 'unused' is stored outside the scope of this variable. Such a pointer will become invalid.
false
2
    {
      ret_ptr= &unused;
    }
------------
```

Regarding the question [Pointer to local variable outside the scope of its declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473875/2789312), if I understand that correctly, `malloc` and `free` should be used for refactoring. My question is if there is an other appropriate refactoring alternative. For instance using of [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

`ret_ptr = std::make_unique<gearman_return_t>();`

Comment: You need to show more of the code including how the function is used.  Links to source are not appropriate for SO questions.

Comment: `malloc` and `free` are the old C-style way of solving this problem. In c++ we have smart ptrs, as you mentioned `unique_ptr`. The smart ptrs offer free memory management for pointers (i.e. you don't have to clean up after yourself), and are the more preferred way to solve this problem in c++

Comment: You should decide which language you are talking about. C and C++ are totally different languages. There is no such thing as `std::unique_ptr` in C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ret_ptr` parameter to the function in question is expected to point to a variable in the calling function.  This pointer is then dereferenced for both reading and writing this external variable.

The `if (ret_ptr == NULL)` block checks whether the caller actually passed in the address of some variable.  If not, this pointer is then made to point to the local variable `unused` so that the pointer can still be safely dereferenced later in the code.  But since `ret_ptr` now points to a local, changes made by dereferencing it are not seen outside the function.  This is fine, since the caller passed in `NULL` for `ret_ptr`.  Similarly, since `ret_ptr` is a parameter, any changes to it are not visible outside of the function.

Nothing needs to be refactored here. The code works as intended with regard to `ret_ptr`. This is a false positive from PVS-Studio.

EDIT:

This is **NOT** a false positive.  The `unused` variable is defined at a lower scope than `ret_ptr`, namely the scope of the first `if` block in the function.  After the `if` block, `ret_ptr` is then dereferenced.  If it was pointing to `ununsed`, that variable is now out of scope and dereferencing `ret_ptr` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To fix this, `unused` must be declared and assigned to above the `if` block:

```
gearman_job_st *gearman_worker_grab_job(gearman_worker_st *worker_shell,
                                        gearman_job_st *job,
                                        gearman_return_t *ret_ptr)
{
    gearman_return_t unused;
    if (ret_ptr == NULL)
    {
        ret_ptr= &unused;
    }

    if (worker_shell and worker_shell->impl())
    {
        ...
    }

    assert(*ret_ptr != GEARMAN_MAX_RETURN);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Change *But since it now points to a local, the changes it makes are not seen outside the function.* to *But since `ret_ptr` is local, the changes made to it are not seen outside the function.*?

Comment: @NathanOliver I made changes to basically include both statements.

Comment: @dbush Thanks.  Great answer.

Comment: IMO you should have deleted your answer and posted the corrected interpretation in a new one; many original votes on this answer are for completely different content. Regardless, the new one is right.